# How can I add the Company Name to the Billing Address information in a new order email?

Tags: orders, email-templates, billing-address

How can I add the Company Name to the Billing Address information in a new order email? I would like to see the customer name, company name (which is a required field), and the rest of the address. But I'm not sure how to go about doing this?

Comment: So you have the field when people order already there?

Comment: When the customer goes to checkout, their company name is a required field. I want to add this information to the confirmation email since it would help our Customer Service.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the attribute as a field to the tables `sales_flat_quote_address` and `sales_flat_order_address`. Then update you config.xml to copy the attributes when the address is converted from quote to order.

```
<sales_convert_quote_address>
    <your_attribute>
        <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
        <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
    </your_attribute>
<sales_convert_quote_address>
```

Now once this is done the item should be on the address object that you have in the email so simply calling `$address->getYourAttribute()` should work here.